# Svelte: Data flow between components - how to pass state of children to parent(s)

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-store

I haven't been using svelte for very long but I can see a couple ways to go about doing what I need, but they are all feel "un-svelte", so I'm hoping there's a more obvious solution I'm missing. Here is the layout code before I go on about what I need it to do.

```html
        <ControlGroup>
            <ControlLabel label='Language'>
                <Select options={lang_options} on:select={(e) => $settings.lang = e.detail} />
            </ControlLabel>
            <ControlLabel label='Visibility'>
                <Select options={...} on:select />
                <Select options={...} on:select />
            </ControlLabel>
            <ControlLabel label='Some other setting'>
                <Select options={...} on:select />
                <Select options={...} on:select />
            </ControlLabel>
        </ControlGroup>
```

First, the deepest nested elements (selects), need to update one or many stores. So far so good, the `on:select` directive makes quick work of that.

Second, the selects all have a `defaultoption`, which if none is provided will be `options[0]`. The `<ControlGroup>` needs to be aware if the selects within itself are default. Because when they aren't, a button to reset the selects should be visible, and clicking that should run the `reset()` function in the selects.

More broadly, the `<ControlGroup>` and `<ControlLabel>` components are there to structure the layout, they don't have any complicated logic. They use svelte slots to pass down components. Worth noting, I wrote the multiselects so it's not an opaque library and I can add stuff to them if that's part of the solution.

So without having a reactive `let` for every single control and then passing lists of those to the controlgroups, what can I do to pass the currently selected value of each select to their parents?

Thank you !

Edit, Current solution:

Top level

```html
        <ControlGroup name='General Settings'>
            <ControlLabel label='Language'>
                <Select id='lang' options={lang_options} selected={lang_current} on:select={(e) => $settings.lang = e.detail} />
            </ControlLabel>
            <ControlLabel label='Visibility'>
                <Select id='visi' options={yesno} on:select={(e) => $settings.visibility = e.detail} />
            </ControlLabel>
            <ControlLabel label='Show Item Level'>
                <Select id='ilvl' options={yesno} on:select={(e) => $settings.showItemLevel = e.detail} />
            </ControlLabel>
        </ControlGroup>
```

ControlGroup.svelte

```js
    let isDefault = true;

    const checkDefault = () => {
        for (var id in controls) {
            if (controls[id].value === controls[id].defaultoption) continue;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };

    const reset = () => {
        for (var id in controls) controls[id].reset();
    };

    if (group) setContext(group, {
        onmount: (id, reset, defaultoption) => controls[id] = {reset, defaultoption},
        ondestroy: (id) => delete controls[id],
        onselect: (id, value) => {
            controls[id].value = value;
            isDefault = checkDefault();
        }
    })
```

Select.svelte

```js
    const groupContext = getContext(group);
    if (groupContext) groupContext.onmount(id, reset, defaultoption?.value);
    $: if (groupContext) groupContext.onselect(id, selected?.value);

    onDestroy(() => {
        if (!groupContext) return;
        groupContext.ondestroy(id);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question. But below I show how you can use get- and setContext to pass a value to the parent.

Parent.svelte:

```
import { setContext } from "svelte";

setContext("aParentId", (childId, value) => {
  // function to show child notification in the parent
  console.log(childId, value);
}
```

Child.svelte:

```
import { getContext } from "svelte";

const notifyParent = getContext("aParentId");

// notify parent if value changes
$: if (value) notifyParent(aChildId, value)
```

Comment: The issue with that is I would need to pass a parentid to the controlgroup, and pass this parentid to each control. Then to be able to figure out if all the controls are set to default, each one would need to be given a unique id, and then have to pass the reset function from each one to the parent to be stored for later.
Which sure, I know how, but it seems like a lot of hardcoded stuff when the selects all share a parent. What about giving only the controlgroup an id/prop and it being passed down to through the slots. Not sure if that's possible though

Comment: Realized context is limited to children of the setter, so I can just set it to 'controlgroup' without passing a specific id to it, and in the selects I just getContext('controlgroup'). So in the end the only top level boilerplate is adding unique ids to the selects which is quite acceptable :)